# Null point exception, no idea why?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

Ok, I'm semi new to java and I am making a pong game. I want to do it completely by myself, but I've come to a problem. I have got 2 classes so far. My main one, and one which contains information about the ball. 
My main class is as follows:

```
    import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int Width=800;
    public static int Height=600;
    public boolean Running=false;
    public Thread thread;
    public Ball ball;
    public int BallX = ball.BallLocationX;
    public int BallY = ball.BallLocationY;



    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main game = new Main();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(Width, Height);
        frame.setTitle("Pong By Poo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        game.start();
        }


    public void start(){
        if(Running==true){
            return;
        }
        else {
            Running=true;
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }



    public void run(){
        while(Running==true){
            Draw();
        }

    }

    public void Draw(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs==null){
            createBufferStrategy(2);
        }else{
            Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(BallX, BallY, 10, 10);   
        }


    }

}
```

And my ball class is this:

```
    **import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Ball extends JPanel{
    public int BallLocationX;
    public int BallLocationY;
    public boolean BallMovementY; //true makes the ball go up, false makes it go down
    public boolean BallMovementX; //True makes the ball go right, false makes it go left.

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(BallLocationX, BallLocationY, 10, 10);
    }

    //moves the ball left to right
    public int YVelocity(){

        if(BallMovementY==true){
            BallLocationY++;
        }
        else{
            BallLocationY--;
        }

        return BallLocationY;

    }

    //Moves the ball up and down
    public int XVelocity(){

        if(BallMovementX==true){
            BallLocationX++;
        }
        else{
            BallLocationX--;
        }

        return BallLocationX;

    }
}
**
```

Im trying to draw the ball on the screen inside my main class, useing the location of the ball which I get from the ball class.
I know that (As of yet) The ball wont move, Ill figure that out later. My probmlem is that it wont draw the ball on screen, getting me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:20)
    at Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Thanks!

Comment: ball is never initialized

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public Ball ball;  // ball is not initialized
public int BallX = ball.BallLocationX;  // NPE here
public int BallY = ball.BallLocationY;
```

Here's the problem. In your instance variable declaration, your `ball` is still pointing to `null` and you have used it to access `BallLocationX`. It will throw a `NPE`.

You should initialize your `ball` reference to point to an instance of `Ball` first: -

```
public Ball ball = new Ball();  // Or whatever way you use to instantiate it
public int BallX = ball.BallLocationX;
public int BallY = ball.BallLocationY;
```

---

**An Advice : -**

- I just noticed that, you have used `public modifier` for all your
  `fields`. You should not do that. As far as possible, try to have
  `private modifier` for your fields, and provide `public accessors` to
  access them. (*getters and setters*).
- Also, follow Java Naming Conventions. Variable names should start with lowercase alphabets/underscore/dollar symbol (Change `BallX` to `ballX` and `BallLocationX` to `ballLocationX`)

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR.. Ah! Actually no. Was a mistyping. Edited it. Thanks :)

Comment: Ahhhh!!!! Thanks so much! Ive got it now, thanks for the fast replie aswell!

Comment: Ok, This is anouther question and just a quick one, I've fixed that problem, and made it so the balls location moves, but now when it comes up on screen there is a streak that is behind the ball? like a line which stays perminantly?
If I need to post the code, just say and I will.

Comment: @NikitaPond.. Is there some more code which is drawing that line? And is that streak from the starting, or it is left behind by the moving ball?

Comment: Left behind by the ball moving. So the ball bounces off each side ect moving, all the time leaving this black line behind it. I relized that I forgot to dispose 'g' so Did that, but it made no differance.

Comment: @NikitaPond.. Sorry, but I'm afraid I can't help you. I'm not so technically strong in Swing. :( So, no idea how it is done. I think you can post it as a new question, with relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You define `ball`, but don't initialize it with any value and then call a method on `ball`, which is `null`.

```
public Ball ball;
public int BallX = ball.BallLocationX;
```

An advice: please don't use `public` fields unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Comment: Ive seen others who say this, but always wondered why?  I meen, does it cause lagg, because it surly doesnt make any differance?

Comment: @NikitaPond making your instance variables private restricts other objects from access your data directly.

Comment: But why is that needed? Is it to stop hacking or somthing?

Comment: Because you break the concept of encapsulation. Read about it.

Answer (score 0):

frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); could be the issue.  Comment this and try.

Comment: I did a line count quickly and the NullPointerException failed on line 26, which is `Main game = new Main();`